# Return array key and value from ordered number

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I want to return both the key and value of an array item, from only knowing their numerically ordered number.

Is there a better method than using these two functions?

```
$num = '3';
$array = [
        'fish' => 'blue',
        'monkey' => 'green',
        'pig' => 'blue',
        'cat' => 'yellow',
];

echo array_values($array)[$num]; // yellow
echo array_keys($array)[$num]; // cat
```

Comment: No, there isn't. You could wrap those two in your own function to return both values at once...

Comment: No, that's about the simplest way to do it. You could iterate over the array & count items, but that's just making it more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$num = '3';
$array = [
        'fish' => 'blue',
        'monkey' => 'green',
        'pig' => 'blue',
        'cat' => 'yellow',
];


$newArray = array_slice($array, $num, 1);
var_dump($newArray);
```

works perfectly well for associative arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option with a `foreach` loop

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
     if($count == 3){
          echo $key.' '.$value;
     }
     $count++;
}
```

But your current method is probably better.